# jQuery how do I .slideUp() the current image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some trouble trying to .slideUp() the current image. All it does is .slideUp() the image that is behind the link I am clicking. I'm not sure how to get the path for the current image and than slide that image up.

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="image_gallery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<section>
    <h1>Image Gallery</h1>
    <ul id="image_list">
        <li><a href="images/casting1.jpg" title="Casting on the Upper Kings">Upper Kings</a></li>
        <li><a href="images/casting2.jpg" title="Casting on the Lower Kings">Lower Kings</a></li>
        <li><a href="images/catchrelease.jpg" title="Catch and Release on the Big Horn">Big Horn</a></li>
        <li><a href="images/fish.jpg" title="Catching on the South Fork">South Fork</a></li>
        <li><a href="images/lures.jpg" title="The Lures for Catching">Lures</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h2 id="caption">Casting on the Upper Kings</h2>
    <p id="gallery">
        <img src="images/casting1.jpg" alt="Image Gallery area" id="image">
    </p>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

The JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#image_list a").each(function() {
        // get the image URL and caption for each image
        var imageURL = $(this).attr("href");
        var caption = $(this).attr("title");

        // preload the image for each link      
        var galleryImage = new Image();
        galleryImage.src = imageURL;

        // set up the event handlers for each link
        $(this).click(function(evt) {
            $("#gallery img").slideUp(2000);
            $("#image").attr("src", imageURL);
            $("#caption").text(caption);

            // cancel the default action of each link
            evt.preventDefault();
        }); // end click 
    }); // end each
    // move the focus to the first link
    $("#image_list:first-child:first-child").focus();
}); // end ready
```

Comment: please provide codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: Remove `$(this).click(function(evt) {` outside the foreach please.

Comment: I'm not sure what either of those are

Comment: I'm not sure how removing `$(this).click(function(evt) {` would help?

Comment: It does not belong inside the each loop, although it doesnt help its up to you, but it should be kept outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this from the each loop:

```
$(this).click(function(evt) {
    $("#gallery img").slideUp(2000);
    [....]
});
```

Then put this outside the loop:

```
$('#image_list a').on('click', function(){
    var imageURL = $(this).attr("href");
    var caption = $(this).attr("title");
    $("#image").attr("src", imageURL);
    $("#caption").text(caption);
    return false;
});
```

If you want a slide effect use the complete event:

```
$('#image_list a').on('click', function(){
    var imageURL = $(this).attr("href");
    var caption = $(this).attr("title");
    $('#gallery img').slideUp( "slow", function() {
        $("#image").attr("src", imageURL);
        $("#caption").text(caption);
        $('#gallery img').slideUp( "slow" );
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: How and where do I `.slideUp()` the current image?

Comment: That is sliding up the list of links not the current image. In the code I provided It was switching to the image behind the link and then sliding up that image not the current image.

Comment: I updated the id also that was incorrect by me @JacobPeterson

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it like this:

```
$(this).click(function(evt) {
    $("#gallery img").slideUp(2000, function(){
        $("#image").attr("src", imageURL);
        $("#caption").text(caption);
});
```

Thanks for showing me how to create that function thing it solved my issue!

Comment: Nice, remember to put it outside the each loop for performance purpose